# OracleBulk Copy problems with DateTime/String to Timestamp

Tags: c#, .net

I´m having problems using OracleBulkCopy.

My code:

```
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DATE", "DATE");  
bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 999999;              
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TABLE_DESTINATION";
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTableCreated);
```

In my Datatable(DataTableCreated), I have a column named DATE with DataTime data( dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:sstt ) .
In DB, I have a column with TimeStamp(6) data.

When I try to insert the info, I get the following error:
"ORA-26041: DATETIME/INTERVAL datatype conversion error"

I´ve tried clone the Datatable and after I change the DataType from DateTime to String.
Same error.
My date is ok(I think), example: "30/12/2013 17:00:30", even trying to set null value in Date.

So,
I need to put the DATE in Oracle Database in timestamp format but I can´t.

---

EDIT: all the code:

```
DataSet dsGetData = new DataSet("TEST");

AseCommand comGetData= new AseCommand();
comGetData.Connection = conSybase;
comGetData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comGetData.CommandText = "PROC_GET";

AseDataAdapter daGetData= new AseDataAdapter();
daGetData.SelectCommand = comGetData;
daGetData.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;


daGetData.Fill(dsGetData, "TEST");      


conOracle.Open();

using (OracleBulkCopy bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(conOracle))
{
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DATE", "DATE");  
bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 999999;              
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TABLE_DESTINATION";
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dsGetData.Tables["TEST"]);
}
conOracle.Close();
```

---

or changing the column type:

```
DataSet dsGetData = new DataSet("TEST");

AseCommand comGetData= new AseCommand();
comGetData.Connection = conSybase;
comGetData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comGetData.CommandText = "PROC_GET";

AseDataAdapter daGetData= new AseDataAdapter();
daGetData.SelectCommand = comGetData;
daGetData.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;


daGetData.Fill(dsGetData, "TEST");      


DataTable dtGetDataClone= dsGetData.Tables["TEST"].Clone();
dtGetDataClone.Columns["DATE"].DataType = typeof(DateTime);
foreach(DataRow row in dsGetData.Tables["TEST"].Rows)
{
DateTime? dtData01 = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row["DATE"].ToString()) ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(row["DATE"].ToString());

row["DATE"] = dtData01; 
dtGetDataClone.ImportRow(row);
}

conOracle.Open();

using (OracleBulkCopy bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(conOracle))
{
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DATE", "DATE");  
bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 999999;              
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TABLE_DESTINATION";
bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dsGetData.Tables["TEST"]);
}
conOracle.Close();
```

---

EDIT 2:

I´ve created a local DB(using the name local) and I´ve ran the same script to create the table/columns.
The same script, as following:

```
drop table TABLE_DESTINATION cascade constraints;

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: TABLE_DESTINATION */
/*==============================================================*/
create table TABLE_DESTINATION
(      
   date_Test          TIMESTAMP       
);
```

Ok, table created on another database. 
I can insert the value now. The error doesn´t happen now !!!

Can be a configuration on database ?

Comment: Please post your DataTable definition. Date types have *NO* format. Format comes into play only when you convert from/to a string representation. If you get such an error it means that somewhere you're actually using a string type and didn't realize it. Perhaps your datatable's DATE column is actually a string, not a DateTime column.

Comment: I´ve changed the type using....

dataTableTeste.Columns["DATE"].DataType = typeof(DateTime);

and before "WriteServer", I get the type

....var dateType = dataTableTeste.Columns["DATE"].DataType.FullName;
//



Returning the dateType as System.DateTime

Comment: Changing the column's DataType field doesn't mean the data loaded there will get converted. If you load the data after "changing" the type with string data, the type will change to the actual data type, which is string. Please post the code you are using to load the data. You probably need to add an actual conversion when loading the data using DateTime.Parse or another similar function

Comment: Ok, thanks ! I edited the post with code.
I´m using DataAdapter to load the data.

In Sybase the DATE FORMAT is DATETIME.

Comment: table created on the another database. 
I can insert the value now. The error doesn´t happen now !!!

Can be a configuration on database ?